# Unable to launch Calculator app on real android device using Appium

Tags: android, automation, appium, adb

I am new to mobile automation and learning it using Appium on a real android device. I am just trying to open Calculator app on my android device. However I am unable to launch it. Below are the required code, Appium logs for the reference. Could you please let me know what wrong I am doing here.

PS: I have already checked many posts on stack overflow but none resolved my issue. Hence posting it here.

Thanks in advance

## Code:

```
public class CalculatorTest {

    static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            openCalculator();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println(e.getCause());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void openCalculator() throws Exception {

        //Setting mobile capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi 6 Pro");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("udid","0986fbcd0805");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","9 PKQ1.180917.001");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.miui.calculator");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity");

        //Setting Url
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        //setting driver
        driver = new AndroidDriver(url,desiredCapabilities);
        System.out.println("application started");
    }
}
=============================================================================================
Appium Logs:
```

```
    C:\Windows\system32>appium --session-override
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[debug] [HTTP] Request idempotency key: cb13604d-ed61-4f3d-9787-2ed0116804ec
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk","appium:appActivity":"com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity","appium:appPackage":"com.miui.calculator","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Redmi 6 Pro","appium:platformVersion":"9 PKQ1.180917.001","appium:udid":"0986fbcd0805","platformName":"android"}}}
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk","appium:appActivity":"com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity","appium:appPackage":"com.miui.calculator","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Redmi 6 Pro","appium:platformVersion":"9 PKQ1.180917.001","appium:udid":"0986fbcd0805","platformName":"android"}}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1654178822963 (19:37:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[Appium] Appium v1.22.3 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.70.1) session
[debug] [Appium] There are no active sessions for cleanup
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:appActivity": "com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:appPackage": "com.miui.calculator",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "Redmi 6 Pro",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "9 PKQ1.180917.001",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "0986fbcd0805"
[debug] [BaseDriver]   },
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[debug] [BaseDriver]     {}
[debug] [BaseDriver]   ]
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: da959f17-91bd-4fea-8410-b6d1f9643c98
[BaseDriver] Using local app 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
[ADB] Found 1 'build-tools' folders under 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk' (newest first):
[ADB]     F:/Downloads/android_sdk/build-tools/32.0.0
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices
[debug] [ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"0986fbcd0805","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: 0986fbcd0805
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to 0986fbcd0805
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 28
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 9
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 28
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell 'settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy 1''
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 wait-for-device'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell echo ping'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('3.4.0' >= '3.4.0')
[debug] [ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
[debug] [ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell appops set io.appium.settings android:mock_location allow'
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logs capture with command: F:\\Downloads\\android_sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 logcat -v threadtime
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to local port 8201
[debug] [ADB] Forwarding system: 8201 to device: 6790
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 forward tcp:8201 tcp:6790'
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 0986fbcd0805 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[debug] [ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is greater or equal to the application version name ('4.27.0' >= '4.27.0')
[debug] [UiAutomator2] io.appium.uiautomator2.server installation state: sameVersionInstalled
[debug] [ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk
[ADB] Using 'apksigner.jar' from 'F:\Downloads\android_sdk\platform-tools\apksigner.jar'
[debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-15.0.1\\bin\\java.exe' -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar F:\\Downloads\\android_sdk\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar verify --print-certs C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - -
[HTTP]
[HTTP] Could not cache the response identified by 'cb13604d-ed61-4f3d-9787-2ed0116804ec', because it has not been completed
[HTTP] Does the client terminate connections too early?
    [Logcat] Logcat terminated with code 0, signal null
```

Stacktrace:

```
> Task :CalculatorTest.main()
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:225)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:151)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:116)
    at appiumTests.CalculatorTest.openCalculator(CalculatorTest.java:39)
    at appiumTests.CalculatorTest.main(CalculatorTest.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6FC8K77', ip: '192.168.0.123', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:146)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$6(RetryRequest.java:83)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:48)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Execution.executeSync(Execution.java:128)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:379)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get(FailsafeExecutor.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$7(RetryRequest.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$createSession$0(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$6(RetryRequest.java:83)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:48)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Execution.executeSync(Execution.java:128)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:379)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get(FailsafeExecutor.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$7(RetryRequest.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$createSession$0(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:4723 after 600000 ms
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2086)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:66)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:4723 after 600000 ms

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:4723 after 600000 ms
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:4723 after 600000 ms

    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:50)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:715)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:703)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:790)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: @Robert Yes i changed it to 127.0.0.1 but still getting same results. Not getting whats exact issue is here.

Comment: Are you sure the server is accessible via 127.0.0.1? You also forgot to add the exact error message and stack trace you get to your question. Please edit it and do so (please don't try to post a stack trace in comments).

Comment: @Robert I added that as well. Kindly look once.

Comment: Its kind of on priority as I am working on a project. Kindly acknowledge if anyone trying to resolve this issue. Appreciate it in advance.

Comment: Moved a bit closer, 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is not installed error is resolved. Updated the logs as well.

Comment: Yes, As i said i have  updated the logs. Earlier it was showing not installed. But still unable to launch app and same stacktrace.

Comment: Finally able to resolve all issue. Incorrect apksigner.jar was being used. Now able to launch the app

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this situation is by using  ADB command to start the activity.
The command looks like this :
`adb shell am start -n com.oneplus.calculator/.Calculator`

To do this with Java, I have used ProcessBuilder :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c" , "C:\\PATH\\TO\\YOUR\\adb.exe",  "shell", "am", "start", "-n", "com.oneplus.calculator/.Calculator");
        Process pc = pb.start();
        pc.waitFor();
```

Here is the full code sample for reference ( JDK 17,  Appium 1.22 , Appium Java lib 8.5.1 ).
Please do change the path to ADB.exe

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","OnePlusNordCE");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName","UiAutomator2");
        //capabilities.setCapability("udid" , "023b6e0b");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);


       capabilities.setCapability("appWaitPackage", "com.oneplus.calculator");
        capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity","com.oneplus.calculator.Calculator"); 
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);    
        
        
        //adb shell am start -n com.oneplus.calculator/.Calculator
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c" , "C:\\PATH\\TO\\YOUR\\adb.exe",  "shell", "am", "start", "-n", "com.oneplus.calculator/.Calculator");
        Process pc = pb.start();
        pc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Done");     
            
            try {
                
                driver.findElement(AppiumBy.id("com.oneplus.calculator:id/digit_2")).click();
                WebElement plus=driver.findElement(AppiumBy.id("com.oneplus.calculator:id/op_add"));
                plus.click();
                WebElement four=driver.findElement(AppiumBy.id("com.oneplus.calculator:id/digit_6"));
                four.click();
                WebElement equalTo=driver.findElement(AppiumBy.id("com.oneplus.calculator:id/eq"));
                equalTo.click();
                WebElement results=driver.findElement(AppiumBy.id("com.oneplus.calculator:id/result"));             
                System.out.println(" result " + results.getText());
            } finally {
                driver.quit();
            }
    }
}
```

PS: I did not got into any error that required apksigner.jar changes. Hope the solution helps other with an alternate option in case they find that the apksigner.jar exception is not the reason but still the app is not popping up on the real device. Also there could be many parameters that are specific to users environment like the app package and app activity.

To find your calculator package and activity use  this command from command prompt ( Assumption is that android device is connected to the machine) :

```
adb shell dumpsys window displays | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus’
```

Result should look like   :

```
 mCurrentFocus=Window{4c3189b u0 com.oneplus.calculator/com.oneplus.calculator.Calculator}
```